# fill random number to new column/ we just add column after we migrate:generate sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

is that possible to use function random numbers to fill new column which is `NULL` in `sequelize` ??

I just alter column to my table and I am afraid that I broke my database , 
oh yea anyway my database id were from 2 and not start by 1 also, how to make it reset to be 1 in `Sequelize`

I am using `postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [getters & setters](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#getters-setters) from sequelize. There you can format or set a value before creating or updating a value. Now if you only want it on the creation, you can use [hooks](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html). There are clear example of how to use both.